# How do a specify a "bundled" identity file for SFTP in Mule?

Tags: mule

I know I can use an absolute system path like `... identityFile="/path/to/key-file" ...`, but that's no good. I'll be deploying the Mule app to various locations with various and sometimes unknown paths. As such the id file needs to be part of the Mule app.

I've imported the id file into src/main/app, but I don't know how to refer to it using a relative path. Can I do something like `${MULE_APP_ROOT}/key-file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discovered that I can use `${app.home}` to refer to the root of my project. So if the key file is in the root of my app, I can use:

```
... identityFile="${app.home}/key-file" ...
```

Comment: That was my problem exactly and ${app.home} was what I needed. Thanks for posting the followup solution!

Comment: If the key file is in the src/main/resources source directory to reference it at runtime you need to use ${app.home}/classes/keyfile.